# How to Pass HTML Form Files to PHP Using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I have a form with a file type input. I want to be able to capture the image attached to this input in JavaScript/jQuery and pass it to my PHP function to then upload to my WordPress media. Using the WordPress `media_handle_upload()` function which according to the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/) requires an index of the `$_FILES` array that the file was sent as the first parameter.

Here's my attempt so far:

HTML

```
<form id="company-logo-form" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="company_logo" multiple="false" id="logo-test"/>
    <input class="btn bg green" name="upload_company_logo" type="submit" value="Upload Image" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$('#company-logo-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let logo = $('#logo-test').prop('files');

    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_url,
        type: 'POST',
        // dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            company_logo: logo,
            action: 'uploadCompanyLogo'
        },
        error: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        },
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
add_action('wp_ajax_uploadCompanyLogo', 'update_company_logo');

function update_company_logo() {
    $logo = $_POST['company_logo'];
    $attachment_id = media_handle_upload($logo, 0);
                
    echo $attachment_id;
}
```

Using this code, when I submit the form I get the following jQuery error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

Comment: Do you have a code sandbox? In which line are you getting error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) in the javascript to properly send the data.

Something like that:

```
$('#company-logo-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let logo = $('#logo-test').prop('files')[0]; // Since 'files' is array.
    let formData = new FormData(); // Create a new form.
    formData.append('action', 'uploadCompanyLogo');
    formData.append('company_logo', logo);

    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false, // No content type headers.
        processData: false, // Do not process sent data.
        error: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        },
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
});
```